# Scripting Tests - TestComplete

Tags: testcomplete

I am complete new to TestComplete. I have a task in hand due to which I have to learn this. I want to know the difference between 'Recording a Script test' and 'Writing Scripts from the scratch'. I am more interested in the latter using JScript as my scripting language.

Please guide me how to design scripts from the scratch with best design tactics. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first you should have a general idea of any automation tool.
Test complete is an automation tool, which is mainly used for writing the automation scripts in many languages including Jscript .

We can create the automation scripts in many ways -
1. "Recording a Script test" means record the user's action performed (generally a test flow), so once recorded you can run it many times as you want. It will basically generated all code from you instead of you write them .
2. there is on other way "Writing Scripts from the scratch" means you will write the all code(Script) by your self which you can make more robust and dynamic , it is generally a good approach .

for learning it you can follow these videos 
https://support.smartbear.com/screencasts/testcomplete/

Answer (score 0):

A recorded script test contains a list of actions you performed during recording. When writing scripts manually, you can add advanced logic like conditional (if..then, switch) blocks or loops (for, while, ...), add complex procedural or even object oriented logic.

The best approach is to combine these two ways. So, you can record a general flow of actions to perform a specific set of steps and then modify the recorded test manually to make it do anything you want. When creating script tests from scratch, you actually will end up with the same result, but will spend more time on this.

So, for a beginner, recording tests and then modifying them if needed seems to be the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Recording a test takes into account flow of actions.
Any test script can be recorded in TestComplete by following the test case.And screen variables needs to be modified with logic.

While Recording a Test, we get the Alias Name of the Object after which we can try the action by doing some tinkering on the recorded script.

Both Recording Script and Scripting are required for effective Automation of test case.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TestComplete.  I did exactly what you're doing.  What I first did was record tests in order to see how TestComplete sees and understands the application under test.  I then took those recorded scripts apart and then used them as the building blocks for my own test script libraries, which I then used to build tests for other people to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Recording means that a gui windows will take over and record all actions that the user makes on the runtime stack. This recording can be played back and rerun all of the actions that the user undertook.

If you write scripts from scratch it is similar in that you can call for testcomplete to run actions taken in that script onto the application you are trying to test.